# CakePHP 3 error.log file - missing JS controller information

Tags: cakephp

I'm working with CakePHP 3. How can I fix error which I keep receiving in error.log file saying that Controller class Js could not be found. The page as well as jquery works just fine. I just do not know why this error appears and how to fix it.

```
Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class Js could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'Js',
  'plugin' => NULL,
  'prefix' => NULL,
  '_ext' => NULL,
)
Request URL: /js/jquery.min.js
Referer URL: http://.../
Client IP: ...
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/.../webroot/index.php(36): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#1 {main}
```

Comment: any update on this topic? I face the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I still have not found the answer. Please let me know if you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the error message is very missleading. 
In my case it was a permission problem with the /js directory.
The solution for me was

```
#either the ugly brute force way:
chmod 0777 -R js
#or the bad way:
cd /js ; chmod +x *.js
```

A more elegant (the good) way would be to add the user to the owners group. 
For example:
The executing user is docker but the owner of the code directory is ec2-user (which belongs to group ec2-user).
To do it the elegant way you simply could do the following:

```
#docker is the user who executes php
#ec2-user is the group of the code owner
#sudo usermod -aG <User> <Group>
sudo usermod -aG docker ec2-user
```

Don't forget to restart the terminal session for your user to let the new group configuration take effect.

hth
Patrick